# How to center my window in another application's window?

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

My application is distributed via App Store (just to let you know about some limitations). I would like to center my application in the frontmost app window. Is it possible?

The only thing I need to know is the frame of the frontmost application. I checked `NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication` but there is nothing about the window's position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for that. It looks like it doesn't even require Accessibility permission.

```swift
if let activeApp = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication {
   (CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo([.excludeDesktopElements, .optionOnScreenOnly], kCGNullWindowID) as [AnyObject]?)?
        .first { $0.object(forKey: kCGWindowOwnerPID) as? pid_t == activeApp.processIdentifier }
        .flatMap { $0.object(forKey: kCGWindowBounds) as CFDictionary? }?
        .flatMap {
            guard let bounds = CGRect(dictionaryRepresentation: $0) else { return }
            print("Active window bounds: \(bounds)")
        }
}
```

Also, keep in mind:

> The coordinates of the rectangle are specified in screen space, where the origin is in the upper-left corner of the main display.